# Detecting features like holes in components

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to get data on hole features on a component within a model - quantity and diameter? The specific use case we are looking at is to determine the size and quantity of bolts required for a component/assembly - bolts, nuts and washers are often not modelled by our customers. Example - if we can determine that a component has 4 x 13mm holes, we can programatically add 4 x M12 bolts to the BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to perform a geometric approach, the viewer is loading simple geometry, it is not a parametric CAD modeler. You could pre-process the CAD seed file to add custom properties in Inventor for example, you can then access those in the component properties in the viewer.

To get access to the geometry (vertices & faces) in the viewer take a look at this post: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/accessing-mesh-information-with-the-view-data-api.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Phillipe. Your blog post is helpful.

Comment: Please accept as response answer or let me know how we could assist you further on that topic. Thanks